# Symfony Doctrine Relationships between 3 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am new with Symfony. I am working with version 3. I simplified my example. I have 3 Tables, for this tables I created a class for each one.

Table "Person": id | name 
Table "Group": id | groupname
Table "PersonGroup": id | person | group

Every Person could be in several groups and every groups can have several persons. In the table PersonGroup I connect the persons with the groups. In my Controller I want to request in which group the selected person is. But in the Dump I only have the data from the PersonGroup table and not the details from the Group (in this example the name):

```
PersonGroup {#485 ▼
  -id: 5
  -person: Person {#456 ▼
    -id: 4
    -name: "Adam"
    -personGroups: PersistentCollection {#445 ▶}
  }
  -group: Group {#486 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 5
    -name: null
    -personGroups: null
     …2
  }
}
```

My Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/person/{personId}", name="personController")
 */
public function showAction($personId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $item = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $personId]);

    foreach ($person->getPersonGroup() as $personGroup) {
        dump($personGroup);
    }

    return $this->render('person/detail.html.twig', [
        'person' => $person
    ]);
}
```

Person class / entity:

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PersonGroup", mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $personGroups;

    /**
     * Item constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personGroups= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

     /**
     * @return ArrayCollection*
     */
    public function getPersonGroups()
    {
        return $this->personGroups;
    }
}
```

Group class/Entity:

```
class Group
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\PersonGroup", mappedBy="group")
         */
        private $personGroups;

    /**
     * Item constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personGroups= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

     /**
     * @return ArrayCollection*
     */
    public function getPersonGroups()
    {
        return $this->personGroups;
    }
}
```

PersonGroup class / entity:

```
class PersonGroup 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", inversedBy="group")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $person;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group",  inversedBy="person")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $group;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Person
     */
    public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     */
    public function setPerson(Person $person)
    {
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    /**
     * @return Group
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }

    /**
     * @param Group $group
     */
    public function setGroup(Group $group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Every Person could be in several groups and every groups can have several persons. ` This sounds more like a `ManyToMany`relationship to me. Which makes the `PersonGroup`Entity obsolete.

Comment: No. I've had too many cases where I later wanted to add extra information about a connection (for example: timestamp of creation) that I stopped using ManyToMany, and use a ManyToOne and OneToMany instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to your Group entity from PersonGroup

```
/**
 * @Route("/person/{personId}", name="personController")
 */
public function showAction($personId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $item = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $personId]);

    foreach ($person->getPersonGroup() as $personGroup) {
        dump($personGroup->getGroup());
    }

    return $this->render('person/detail.html.twig', [
        'person' => $person
    ]);
}
```

But you should create a custom function in Group repository and Person repository to retrieve the correct entity.

**EDIT**

1. If you want te retrieve all the Group entity you should add a parameter fetch="EAGER" to your relations, it will automatically do aan innerJoin on your relation.

> ```
> class PersonGroup 
> {
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
>      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      */
>     private $id;
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", inversedBy="group", fetch="EAGER")
>      * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
>      */
>     private $person;
>
>     /**
>      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group",  inversedBy="person", fetch="EAGER")
>      * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
>      */
>     private $group;
> ```

2. For example if you want to get All Groups from a Person you can do a custom repository function.

Ex:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\Person;

/**
 * GroupRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class GroupRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findByPerson(Person $person){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
            ->leftJoin('g.personGroups', 'pg')
            ->leftJoin('pg.person', 'p')
            ->where('p.id = :personId')
            ->setParameter('personId', $person->getId())
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Your code exampl: The dump returns me a group object with id but no name. 2. In repository's I can create custom database requests, do you mean, I should build there a custom function which return me the groups?